# Redshift COPY from JSON - null string as a timestamp

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Trying to load JSON file to Redshift table using COPY command.

Data in JSON contains timestamp value that can be null. The `null` is wrapped in double quotes - `shipDate: "null"`.

Redshift's obviously considering it as string value and trying to convert it to the `TIMESTAMPTZ` but it fails.

`stl_load_errors` says that I'm trying to load `Invalid data`

Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quantum.quantum_customer_order_update
(
    order_id     VARCHAR(50) DISTKEY,
    ship_date    TIMESTAMPTZ
)
    DISTSTYLE KEY
    SORTKEY (order_id);
```

JSON with data:

```
{"orderId" : "88e52685ee8097b91d182b4fc4f64adf", "shipDate" : "null"}
```

Copy command

```
COPY orders(order_id, ship_date)
    FROM 's3://bucket/orders.json'
    ACCESS_KEY_ID ''
    SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ''
FORMAT AS JSON 's3://bucket/json_paths.json'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto';
```

Is there a way how to make Redshift COPY store the value from `shipDate` property as NULL value? Thx

Comment: Have you tried the "NULL AS 'null'" option to COPY?  It *SHOULD* do what you want.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-null-as

Comment: NULL argument is not supported for JSON based COPY

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I suspect your best option is to ingest into a staging table with this column as varchar.  Then INSERT into your target table with the timestamp column but converting 'null' to NULL.  Other than that I think you would need to preprocess your json to remove the "null" keys.  Your example would become - {"orderId" : "88e52685ee8097b91d182b4fc4f64adf"}.  An ingest table is likely easier.